# Reading successive images of a video file in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

I'm currently working on a project and at the moment I need to pull successive frames from a video then find and match features on them. The problem Is that when I call VideoCapture::read(Mat &image) It overwrites both images that I want to compare with the same image. I think It could be because the same buffer is being used and therefore both values are pointing to the same space. I'm just not certain how to get around this.

Here's the problem code: (don't worry about the poor exception handling)

```
    Mat m1, m2;
VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);
if(!cap.isOpened()){
    throw std::exception("Could not open the file");
}
int num = 0;

while(num < 20){
    try{
    cap.read(m1);
    cap.read(m2);

    num++;  
    match(m1,m2,num);

    }catch(std::exception){
        std::cout << "Oh no!";
    }
}
```

match(m1,m2,num) does the feature detection business and outputs an image "Image_%d.jpg" , num. This image is both images side by side with matches displayed. This image is the same image twice in a row though. match() does work because I have tested it with still images, so I am confident the problem lies in the cap.read code.
Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure both images are the same? If they are successive frames they might be visually the same but actually have very small differences. If that isn't the issue, this page has some info on cloning the frame image (search for VideoCapture::read) - http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

Comment: Yes, They are exactly the same, I have stepped through the images to ensure that. The cloning in the link is applicable to earlier versions and mostly deals with the c IplImage rather than the c++ cv::Mat which is easier to work with. Just setting the image and then cloning the variable that I set it to seems to do the trick though, more or less forcing a deep copy of itself.

Comment: Yep, I saw your answer just after I posted my comment. I'm not really familiar with OpenCV, so not aware of the differences between versions. Just thought I'd share my 5 mins Google research. Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was as easy as making sure each image was a deep copy of the captures image.

```
m1 >> cap
m1 = m1.clone();
```

did the trick, although less elegantly than I hoped for.

Comment: Unless you are just playing drunk, that's not the way of doing it.

Comment: I don't see any other answers here Thomas. Maybe you could provide some actual input instead of just bagging mine. Like I said, it does what I want but it is a hacky way of doing it.

Comment: The OP solved his own problem. No need to downvote! If you don't like it, post your own answer. +1 here to compensate.